# Handle resize event on a structural directive without loosing context

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating a `ngIf` like structual directive to handle with platform.

```
*ifPl="'android'
```

It's working, I mean, if I'm on `ios`, the element isn't in the DOM, else yes.
But I want to go on by handling the `resize` event, imagine I develop on the browser and change the device (it changes the size), so I want the DOM to be added/removed at this moment.

I handled the `resize` with `Renderer2` as below:

```
Renderer2.listen('window', 'resize', this.onResize)
```

But I lost my context in `onResize` function, `this` is undefined... I want to keep the context up in this case.

## Html usage:

```
<div *ifPl="'android'">
  ROMAIN
</div>
```

## Directive.ts

```
@Input('ifPl')
set myIfPl(platform: string) {
  this.platform = platform;
  this._context.$implicit = this._context.ifPlatform = IsThisPlateForm(window, platform);
  console.log(IsThisPlateForm(window, platform))
  this._updateView();
  this.render.listen("window", "resize", this.onResize)
}

private _updateView() {
  if (!this._context.$implicit) {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
  } else {
    this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);
  }
}

onResize(){ console.log(this) } //this == undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the context by below ways

```
this.render.listen("window", "resize", this.onResize.bind(this));

// arrow function
this.render.listen("window", "resize", () => this.onResize());
```

For the second way, if you need the event parameter, you will need to add it in arrow function and transform it into your function.

```
 this.render.listen("window", "resize", (e) => this.onResize(e));
```

Comment: You guy are awesome